# Chrome Extension - How to get external page content?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For example:

I have a url where returns true or false in her content, how can I catch the content?

I tried with XMLHTTPRequest but

XMLHttpRequest cannot load ****. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://ffgkpalnaomhmimcgjmijepkeonpmndl' is therefore not allowed access.

Grateful

Comment: look at options in the extension `manifest.json` file

Comment: my manifest.json http://pastebin.com/fyjpZ1pn what I have to do?